# Assign Numbers to Groups in Calculated Column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, calculated-columns

This is probably extremely easy however for some reason I am having difficulty in pinpointing exactly how to do this. I have a list of names and cities associated with those names. I want to assign a number in a calculated column based on 1) name and 2) city. Example code below:

```
Name       |       City      |   Calculated Column
John               NYC                 1
John               NYC                 1
John               NYC                 1
John                LA                 2
John                LA                 2
Chris              NYC                 1
Chris               SF                 2
Christ              SF                 2 
Chris               LA                 3
```

I am assuming I need to use an over and partition function, but have not been able to properly calculate the 'Calculated Column' above. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use dense_rank as below:

```
Select *, [Computed Column]= dense_rank() over(Partition by [Name] order by City) 
   from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE TEST
(
NAME VARCHAR(10),
CITY VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES 
('John','NYC'),
('John','NYC'),
('John','NYC'),
('John','LA'),
('John','LA'),
('Chris','NYC'),
('Chris','SF'),
('Christ','SF'),
('Chris','LA')

SELECT NAME,CITY,dense_rank() OVER(partition by name ORDER BY city desc) calculated column
FROM TEST

---output---

NAME  CITY calculated column
Chris   SF  1
Chris   NYC 2
Chris   LA  3
Christ  SF  1
John    NYC 1
John    NYC 1
John    NYC 1
John    LA  2
John    LA  2